# Can we add styling to google calendar invitation email body with google calendar api?

Tags: google-calendar-api

So I use the google calendar API to send calendar invitation to the user, can we use styling for the invitation body? like add margin or padding?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can by styling with html in the 'description' field.

I'd suggest you could test this by adding something like this in the description field of your new event invite.

```html
<h1 style="color:red;">I'm red</h1>
```

This works for events, the quick add function doesnt seem to support this though.

To look this up yourself [go here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events) and find the word 'description' on the page, here's what I found in the Calendar API specs when I looked.

[image]

Comment: Sidenote, if it's seeming to hard to style things, I've seen emoji's added to calendar event invitations to good affect.